# Connect Vue JS to backend located on same subnet

Tags: vue.js, frontend, backend

I have 2 servers, both of them located in one subnet. Server 1 has a public IP address and has Vue app. Server 2 has Django application. Vue application should connect to backend in order to use some Api, but server 2 has no connection to internet and could be reached only through local network. How should I set up Vue js app? And can you give me some sources where some people do such things? Or ref to documentation of Vue.

For now, I add configuration to iptables of server 1 record to redirect one of the ports to server 2. But from the point of security, it isn't solving problem.

Comment: I usually hide my services behind a gateway. The gateway has access to all my local services, and applications on the Internet using this gateway to call my internal APIs. Ocelot is a gateway package for .NET Core that I use.